# Specman memory configuration

Tags: specman

I have a server with 20GB of RAM available.
I need to run a regression with Specman, and wish to optimize it, to run at least 5  tests in parallel.
I know my RTL needs a static 2GB memory size, but testbench size varies.
How can I control Specman, in order not to have one test taking the entire memory on the account of the others?

Answer (score 3):

In order to let all 5 simulations use the server's memory without running out of memory is to set the optimal_process_size to 3-4G.
The automatic gc mechanism of specman will do the work and make sure that each process won't run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the optimal_process_size paramater in order to control the amount of memory used by the simulator. This way you take control of the GC process.

Answer (score 0):

Use config memory to specify specman optimal and Max process size, for example :
Config mem -max_process_size=2000M;

If needed, use GC debug options to determine optimal parameters for GC threshold, increments and disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yoi can setenv SPECMAN_MEMORY_FULL_DEBUG.
This env variable sets debug flag.
This way you can explore your test and set the optimal process size.
Also, try to use 32 bit mode. It usually consumes less memory, though it has overall memory limitations compared to 64 bits mode.